# kubectl exec behaving strangely, stating command not found even though the binary is there in the pod

Tags: linux, mongodb, bash, kubernetes, openshift

So have an OpenShift cluster and running a pod in the `mongodb-test` namespace. The pod is running fine

```
$ kubectl get pods -n mongodb-test                                             
NAME               READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
mongodb-1-7ww9k    1/1     Running     0          14m
```

When I exec into the pod and run the `mongo` command, I dont get any issue and the command works as expected.

```
$ kubectl exec -it -n mongodb-test  mongodb-1-7ww9k   -c mongodb  sh
sh-4.2$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3
>
```

Now the problem is when I try to run the same command using below syntax I get `mongo` not found

```
$ kubectl exec -it -n mongodb-test mongodb-1-7ww9k -c mongodb -- sh -c mongo
sh: mongo: command not found
E0227 13:02:01.728579   24237 v3.go:79] EOF
                                           command terminated with exit code 127
```

Below are the output of `echo $PATH` and `which mongo` from inside the pod.

```
$ kubectl exec -ti -n mongodb-test mongodb-1-7ww9k -c mongodb -- sh 
sh-4.2$ echo $PATH
/opt/rh/rh-mongodb36/root/usr/bin:/opt/rh/rh-mongodb36/root/usr/sbin:/opt/app-root/src/bin:/opt/app-root/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
sh-4.2$ which mongo
/opt/rh/rh-mongodb36/root/usr/bin/mongo
sh-4.2$
```

Comment: Can you execute `mongo` using its full path?

Comment: Please, can you update you question with your deployment manifest? I've tried with a regular mongo image and it works. I want to reproduce the exact same scenario you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here is what the problem was. When I tried to execute `mongo` actually after getting inside the pod using the command

```
$ kubectl exec -it -n mongodb-test  mongodb-1-7ww9k   -c mongodb  sh
```

somehow the path to where the `mongo` executable is was being set into `PATH` (through `.bash_profile` :confused), but when I tried to call `mongo`, using the below command, the same was not happening.

```
kubectl exec -it -n mongodb-test mongodb-1-7ww9k -c mongodb -- sh -c mongo
```

Since we suspected the `PATH` was being set in `.bash_profile` I tried to execute `mongo` in bash and below command worked.

```
kubectl exec -it -n mongodb-test mongodb-1-7ww9k -c mongodb -- bash -c mongo
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as below

```
# kubectl run mongo --image=mongo --port=27017

# kubectl exec -it mongo-857dc9fb9d-scknx -- mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.2.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb

if it doesnt work then try below

 # kubectl exec -it mongo-857dc9fb9d-scknx -- /opt/rh/rh-mongodb36/root/usr/bin/mongo
```

Comment: No luck
```
kubectl exec -i -n mongodb-test mongodb-1-7ww9k -- mongo 
exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"mongo\": executable file not found in $PATH"
command terminated with exit code 1
```
I think it has something to do with OpenShift, I think things would work if the same pod is running on normal K8S cluster.

Comment: Hey, including -t wont matter, but I tried and that didnt work.

Comment: The second command also doesnt work. `/opt/rh/rh-mongodb36/root/usr/bin/mongo: error while loading shared libraries: libyaml-cpp.so.rh-mongodb36-0.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`